# Не видет файлы сайта на LINUX, если открывать их локально. "Файл не найден"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache, сервер, apache2

Я делал сайты через LAMP, добавляя все файлы на локальный сервер по пути: var/www/html и всё было прекрасно, но потом он просто перестал видеть файлы в этой папке. Вернее файлы есть, но если открываю в браузере Localhost/index.html открывает коряво, как будто из кэша, файлы которых там уже давно нет, а если из этой папки, "открыть как - Firefox " то выдаст Файл не найден, хотя он лежит именно там.
[image: Вот так выдает, что файла тип нет]

Вот их расположение именно в той папке.
[image: Хотя, файлы на месте.]

Ранее, всё было отлично, я ложил сюда файлы и работал, сейчас как будто путь изменился.
И не смотря на наличе файлов тут, именно в этой папке, открыть в браузере невозможно, мол файл не найден.
[image: Вот если так открывать, то "файл не найден"]
Разрешение, права на изменение и редактирование есть, у всего каталога.

Comment: В тегах указаны `apache` и `сервер`, а почему тогда вы хотите открыть html-файлы не запуская сервер? У меня к вам два вопроса: 1) открывается ли у вас [http://localhost/](http://localhost/) ([http://127.0.0.1/](http://127.0.0.1/)) ? 2) запущен ли у вас apache?

Comment: Меняется ли что-нибудь, если открывать файл не через ассоциацию, а непосредственно из браузера по Ctrl-O?

Comment: да посмотри в инспекторе...